# DELETE Con Volley

Tags: android-studio, android-volley, volley

Ahora mismo tengo problemas al momento de hacer una petición a Volley con el método DELETE. Estoy consumiento un api REST, el cual me funciona en todos los testeadores excepto en mi código usando Volley. He intentado de varias formas y sigue sin funcionar! Alguién que me pueda ayudar?

Este es mi código :

```
    String url = "http://lafina1.jl.serv.net.mx/api/carrito/90/";

    final SpotsDialog progressDialog;

    progressDialog = new SpotsDialog( mContext, R.style.Custom );
    progressDialog.show();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();


    params.put( "productoId", "3" );

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject( params );
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.DELETE, url, parameters,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {


                        Toast.makeText( mContext, "" + response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText( mContext, "ErrorRespuesta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();

            Toast.makeText( mContext, "Error en Elimnar" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            //abrirError();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } );

    mqQueue.add( request );
```

Cuando ejecuto el método en el onErrorResponse me manda este error

> "com.android.volley.ClientError". o simplemente cuando imprimo el error con el getMessage , me sale > "null".

aquí una imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Jorgesys , estaba tratando con el código que me recomendaste ! y de igual manera me arroja el response 400 , este es :

```
    try {
        mqQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        String URL = "http://lafina1.jl.serv.net.mx/api/carrito/92/";

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("productoId", 5);
        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        mqQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

La forma de enviar parametros es esta : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como sugerencia, incluye una traza más completa del error, pues con el pequeñísimo fragmento que pusiste, difícilmente puede deducirse algo

Comment: Amigo Alfabravo , como ves en la imagen sale null al momento de usar el *getMessage* , sabrás cual puede ser la causa del error ? por favor :)

Comment: @NickerPasco por el mensaje com.android.volley.ClientError me parece que tu petición es incorrecta, ¿Obtienes un response code 400?

Comment: @Jorgesys , como añadi en el comentario si . efectivamente está mandando un response 400 con el codigo que me pasaste , pero igual sigo ..!

Comment: Revisa con el administrador que valores son necesarios, de acuerdo a esto puedes determinar que información enviar para evitar un error 400

Answer (score 0):

SIguiendo un caso [muy parecido](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993958/236345) que se encuentra en SO original, el error parece deberse a un problema en la forma que consumes para obtener el JSON. Revisa la respuesta enlazada para ver cómo lo resolvieron.

Ahora, también se trata de revisar el error correctamente. Sugieren hacerlo así:

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error, Status Code " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "URL: " + payOp.getURL());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Payload: " + payOp.getJson().toString());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Net Response to String: " + error.networkResponse.toString());
    Log.i("jsonObjectRequest", "Error bytes: " + new String(error.networkResponse.data));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de registro está imprimiendo lo que parece ser una tontería, porque response.data es realmente una matriz de bytes, no una cadena. Además, un VolleyError es solo una Excepción extendida, por lo que Exception.getMessage () probablemente no devolvería lo que está buscando a menos que anule los métodos de análisis para analizar su VolleyError en su clase de Solicitud extendida. 
usa esto:

```
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     String json = null;

     NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
     if(response != null && response.data != null){
         switch(response.statusCode){
             case 400:
                  json = new String(response.data);
                  json = trimMessage(json, "message");
                  if(json != null) displayMessage(json);
                  break;
             }
            //Additional cases
     }
}

public String trimMessage(String json, String key){
    String trimmedString = null;

    try{
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        trimmedString = obj.getString(key);
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return trimmedString;
}

//Somewhere that has access to a context
public void displayMessage(String toastString){
    Toast.makeText(context, toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por el mensaje que muestras, me parece que el problema es una incorrecta petición

> com.android.volley.ClientError
>
> onErrorResponse: null

seguramente estas teniendo un response code 400, ya que los parámetros que envías son incorrectos.

De hecho realizando una rápida prueba con tu petición efectivamente se obtiene un response code 400 por una petición incorrecta y el mensaje:

> "Required request body is missing: public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
>   pe.edu.idat.lafina.api.controller.CarritoController.removeItem(java.lang.Long,pe.edu.idat.lafina.contracts.CarritoRequest)
>   throws pe.edu.idat.lafina.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa que valores debes enviar en el `body` de tu petición, este es un ejemplo de como agregarlo a tu petición usando Volley:

```
    //Crea body
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("valor1", "1");
        jsonBody.put("valor2", "hola");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
```

y agrega los métodos `getBodyContentType()` y `getBody()` :

```
   JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest( Request.Method.DELETE, url, parameters,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                ...
                ...
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ...
            ...
        }
      }){
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

    };
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo:
[¿Cómo enviar una solicitud usando una volea con cuerpo de cuerda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body/33578202#33578202)